# WPF Commands - Relation of View to the Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to understand a little better the MVVM design pattern for WPF developing and this is a basic question in this subject.

Let's say I got the model implemented and it got a method which does the main action. In the View i want to create a button which will activate this action when pressing it. In order to do so I need to associate the `Click` event with an event handler, which actually is only suppose to call the model method.

The problem is that as I understand, the view doesn't even suppose to know the model. So how can I make the button in the View do the action I want?

Answer (score 2):

That's where the view model comes in. First you should consider using Commands instead of event handlers. With Commands you can bind the "action" to the button instead of hard coding an event to the Click event. Like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ActionCommand}"/>
```

Now your view model have to have a property that implements ICommand. There are a lot of implementations for this, e g RelayCommand in MVVM Light Toolkit. Through this property you call your models action. This is done by a reference to the model that your view model has. The reference to the model could be set through dependency injection or just supplying it at the creation of the view model.

Simple View model class:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model;
    private ICommand _actionCommand;

    public ViewModel(Model model)
    {
        _model = model;
        _actionCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteAction);
    }

    public ICommand ActionCommand
    {
       get { return _actionCommand; }      
    }

    private void ExecuteAction()
    {
       _model.Action();
    }
}
```

This means that your view doesn't really know the type of the ViewModel, just that it has a Command-property called ActionCommand. To set the Views view model you use the View.Datacontext. This can be done in several different ways. Dependency injection could be used here too. Another solution is to use a ViewModelLocator, that uses the Locator pattern to connect the view to its ViewModel.

Comment: I'm aware of the data context but never heard of a ViewModelLocator and not about Dependency Injection...
In your code, what is the ExecuteAction method is used for? Are you using it to define the Command?

Comment: ExecuteAction is where you call your action of the model. This way the ViewModel hides the Model from the View. There are a lot information about both VievModelLocators and Dependency Injection on the Internet. Download MVVM Light Toolkit for instance there you have all of these things in a nice toolkit with source code for you to read.

Answer (score 2):

In your Model you have your function:

```
class MainWindowModel
{
   public void MyAction()
   {...}
}
```

In the constructor of your ViewModel you create an instance of your model like:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
   private readonly MainWindowModel mainWindowModel;

   public MainWindowViewModel()
   {
      this.mainWindowModel = new MainWindowModel();
   }
```

Then you have an implementation of `ICommand` like RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> exectue, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (exectue == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("exectue");
            this.execute = exectue;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }
```

so. now you have a property in your ViewModel:

```
 private ICommand myCommand;
        public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get { return this.myCommand; }
            set
            {
                this.myCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

The OnPropertyChanged-Event you get, when you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`-Interface

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

In your constructor of your ViewModel you instanziate the MyCommand like

```
this.MyCommand = new RelayCommand(MyCommandExecute);
```

Then you have to create a method in your viewmodel where you call the MyAction-Method of your model:

public void MyCommandExecute(object parameter)
{
this.mainWindowModel.MyAction();
}

In your xaml you have to set the DataContext like:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The small viewModel is the Namespace of your ViewModel. This you have to add in the Window-Definition like:

```
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:TestApplication.ViewModel"
```

Now you can bind your button-Command to the ICommand-Property of your ViewModel like:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, and supply an implementation, for which I suggest that you [read this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) on MSDN.

In your ViewModel, you would create an instance of `ICommand`, e.g. `ButtonClick`, which would look something like (based on RelayCommand):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.ButtonClick = new RelayCommand(_ => this.DoSomething());
    }

    public ICommand ButtonClick { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Something...
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml you would bind to `ButtonClick`:

```
<Button Text="Click" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" />
```